# How to animate text change in TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-listview, android-animation

Trying to do the following:

```
animTimeChange = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left); 
itemTime.startAnimation(animTimeChange);
itemTime.setText("new text");
```

but the animation happens thru blank screen (i.e. original text is cleared, then new text appears with animation). How to avoid that blank screen?

(my `TextView` is part of `ListView` row, I've tried to use `TextSwitcher` - [it doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101470/how-to-correctly-use-textswitcher-in-listview/6240183#6240183); for `ViewFlipper` - I am not sure where add Views there, since this is part of the `ListView)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TextSwitcher is exactly what you should be using for this.  Check out the [API Demo for TextSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/TextSwitcher1.html).

The way you should implement this is in your ListAdapter, provide TextSwitcher views to the ListView instead of TextViews.  Then you can just call [TextSwitcher.setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) on the list item you want to change.

Note that you should imediately get rid of your reference to the list item to avoid REALLY messing up listview.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Have you seen my question with TextSwitcher code? It doesn't work properly and I can not understand why.

Comment: @LA_ I did. I added an answer that explains why this is happening.

Comment: Can I use TextSwitcher to animate Toolbar title changes or is there a better way?